# extracting codec information from rpt stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, avconv

I got a list of rtp streams in a list, those are tv channels from my internet provider.

I would like to get information about the codec and get the channel names instead of ip addresses, precisely this kind of info I could get "manually" in vlc :
[image]

I tried `avconv -i rtp://@233.32.36.5:7500` but got nothing interesting; 
avprobe is the same.

I would specifically like to get the last bit of info on the picture, the channel name.

Would anyone know any program, more specifically CLI ones as the list is quite long and I would like to avoid doing it 'by hand' in VLC for the whole list.